# How to create a self incremented sequence id for table

Tags: postgresql

I want a table with two columns id and name

```
id    name
1     Peter
2     Mary
```

The functionality is needed that only insert the name into table and the id can be created automatically in incremental order

something like

```
insert table values
(Jack)

id    name
1     Peter
2     Mary
3     Jack
```

I am using Postgresql 9.3

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
  id serial,
  name  text
)
```

since your table need only one column to `INSERT` make a function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_into_table(val text) RETURNS VOID AS
$$
INSERT INTO test (name) VALUES (val)
$$language sql
```

usage : `SELECT insert_into_table('anyName')`